# sparksql how to resolve Data dependency issues

Tags: apache-spark-sql

```
scala> sql(""" select * from  demo1""").show(false)
+-----+---+
|from1|to1|
+-----+---+
|c    |d  |
|b    |c  |
|a    |b  |
+-----+---+
```

demo1 is my inputTable.
now from table we can find: a to b, b to c,c to d; so we need All elements on the link
will be to d.
so i need result like this:

```
+-----+---+
|from1|to1|
+-----+---+
|c    |d  |
|b    |d  |
|a    |d  |
+-----+---+
```

note: a b c It's not sorted by subtitle or size.
Their relationship transitions are random.
How do I write this SparkSQL?

Comment: His dependence is chaining, no loops, no branches

Comment: may be spark graph is useful